# How to debug VScode extension configuration settings?

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code

Right now I'm debugging my VScode extension. So I run it in one instance of VScode, hit F5 to run it in the other. But - how to gain access to this debugged extension settings panel? I have declared all the settings within my package.json, but I cannot find this debugged plugin listed in any of the instances of VScode, it's there because I can access it via command line, but the extension itself is not listed in the extension lists (it's debugged), so how can I access the settings panel for this particular extension in debug mode?

Comment: Just open  the Settings and navigate to the subsection of Extension for the given extension